# ivy and artifactory resolving failure

Tags: ivy, artifactory, spring-ldap

Having a small issue with ivy, artifactory and the spring repo.  I was attempting to use:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework.ldap"      name="spring-ldap-core" rev="1.3.2.RELEASE"         conf="compile->default"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework.ldap"      name="spring-ldap"      rev="1.3.2.RELEASE"         conf="compile->default"/>
```

with ivy settings:

```
<resolvers>
  <filesystem name="local">
    <ivy pattern="${repository.dir}/[module]/ivy.xml" />
    <artifact pattern="${repository.dir}/[module]/[artifact].[ext]" />
  </filesystem>
  <chain name="chain">
    <resolver ref="local"/>
    <ibiblio name="artifactory-spring" m2compatible="true" root="http://artifactory.xxx.com:8081/artifactory/spring-release"/>
    <ibiblio name="artifactory"        m2compatible="true"  root="http://artifactory.xxx.com:8081/artifactory/repo1"/>
  </chain>
</resolvers>
```

However, I'm getting errors (ant publish -verbose mode)

```
[ivy:cachepath] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://artifactory.xxx.com:8081/artifactory/spring-release/spring-ldap/jars/spring-ldap-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar
[ivy:cachepath]     artifactory-spring: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.springframework.ldap#spring-ldap;1.3.2.RELEASE
[ivy:cachepath]         tried http://artifactory.xxx.com:8081/artifactory/repo1/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom
[ivy:cachepath] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://artifactory.xxx.com:8081/artifactory/repo1/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.2.RELEASE.pom
[ivy:cachepath]         tried http://artifactory.xxx.com:8081/artifactory/repo1/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar
[ivy:cachepath] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=http://artifactory.xxx.com:8081/artifactory/repo1/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar
```

indicating that repo1 doesn't have version 1.3.2 and the spring maven repo doesn't have the pom or anything.  How do I get ivy (or maybe artifactory?) to deal with the spring maven repo properly?  I'm guessing the spring repo is simply not m2compatible, though I've tried flagging the ibiblio setting to false for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a deployment issue.. spring-ldap failed to deliver poms, etc.  Backing down to 1.3.1 works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured your settings file to download from the non-existent "xxx.com" domain.

Good news is that you don't need a settings file at all, by default ivy will download from the [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) repository.

Bad news is that there is no 1.3.2.RELEASE version of the spring-ldap artifact:

- [spring-ldap versons](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.springframework.ldap%22%20AND%20a%3a%22spring-ldap%22)
- [spring-ldap-code versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.springframework.ldap%22%20AND%20a%3a%22spring-ldap-core%22)

The following ivy file works:

```
  <dependency org="org.springframework.ldap"      name="spring-ldap-core" rev="1.3.2.RELEASE"         conf="compile->default"/>
  <dependency org="org.springframework.ldap"      name="spring-ldap"      rev="1.3.1.RELEASE"         conf="compile->default"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.  the 'xxx' domain was just me x'ing out my company name.  We have a local artifactory set up, so yes, I do need the local settings file.  Thanks for the help!